# What are good online resources for learning shell scripting?

Tags: shell, scripting, documentation

I am interested in learning  shell script ompletely. Can anyone suggest some good online resources?

Comment: Can you specify a bit what you want to do? There is too much to read for an entire lifetime based on the current question.

Answer (score 9):

This answer focuses on Bash.

Probably the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) can help you. It has even be translated to French (on [traduc.org](http://abs.traduc.org)).

Also read the [pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) and the [FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) from Greg's wiki.

Comment: ABS is great, but maybe not the place to start learning for a complete beginner.

Answer (score 4):

The best free source for shell scripting I've seen so far:
http://fog.ccsf.cc.ca.us/~gboyd/cs160b/online/index.html

Answer (score 3):

You can check out this site: [Writing Shell Scripts](http://linuxcommand.org/writing_shell_scripts.php). Things have been explained in a very simple language, and the flow is quite good.

Answer (score 2):

There is an upcoming blog about unix and shell. The commands are explained in simple manner. You can try it:

http://learnshell.blogspot.com/

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably worth you while reading the man page for bash (type `man bash` at your prompt) as it covers quite a lot of useful information in a concise manner. Also look at some of the other `man` pages such as `test` (used with `if... while...` statments), `awk` and `sed`. You will find other tutorials probably easier or more useful to read as a beginner, but you will definitely come back to the `man` pages regularly so it helps to get to know them.

My Ubuntu shell has a program called `vimtutor` which looks useful for learning vi.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Bash Scripting Tutorial](http://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/) which is good if you are a beginner.  If you are new to the Linux command line here is a [Linux tutorial](http://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/) which is also good for the beginner.